# Конвертация xls в pdf и ods

Tags: php, excel, windows-server

Есть задача конвертировать xlsx-файлы в pdf и ods для скачивания с сайта.

Как лучше всего организовать этот процесс в автоматическом режиме, имея Windows Server 2012 с установленным Excel?

Файлов xlsx больше ста и они постоянно меняются, поэтому лучше всего, чтобы скрипт запускался прямо со страницы загрузки и выполнялся "на лету".

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет ссылка на [топик в англ. stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223491/how-to-convert-xls-to-pdf-via-php).

Answer (score 1):

В предложенных условиях один из вариантов конвертации реализуется с помощью сервера сценариев Windows (Windows Script Host), vbs-сценария, содержащего команды конвертации, и формирования необходимой командной строки в php с последующим вызовом.

Образец вызова скрипта, формируемый в php :

```
cscript xls-pdf.vbs <полный путь до файла в формате xls>
```

Например:

```
cscript xls-pdf.vbs "D:\07-Проекты\soQu489061 (Конвертация-xls-в-pdf-и-ods)\Excel-PDF-ODS.xlsx"
```

Код скрипта vbs (имя файл **xls-pdf.vbs**)

```
' ограничения: файл XLS с одним листом
' передаваемые параметры
' Полное Имя Файла в формате XLS
' Полное Имя Файла в формате PDF
' Полное Имя Файла в формате ODS
xlsFile = WScript.arguments(0)
' отладка
'MsgBox (xlsFile)

arStr = Split (xlsFile, ".")
'отладка
'MsgBox (arStr(0))
pdfFile = arStr(0) & ".pdf"
odsFile = arStr(0) & ".ods"
' отладка
'MsgBox (pdfFile)
'MsgBox (odsFile)

Set xlsObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'xlsObj.Visible = True
Set xlsWrkBk = xlsObj.WorkBooks.Open (xlsFile)

xlsObj.DisplayAlerts = False
' 60 - OpenDocument Spreadsheet 
xlsWrkBk.SaveAs odsFile, 60
' 0 - PDF
xlsWrkBk.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, pdfFile, 0, True, False,,,False

xlsWrkBk.Close
xlsObj.Quit
WScript.Quit
```